# PostgreSQL extension using GEOS and PostGIS - undefined symbol: lwgeom_geos_error

Tags: c, postgresql, compilation, postgis, geos

I tried to write some PostgreSQL extension, just a simple function based on this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/postgresql-simple-c-extension-development-for-a-no). It 
works but then I want to write an extension which uses some GEOS code. So I wrote function according to Postgis function [ST_RelateMatch](http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/3.1/d8/d5c/lwgeom__geos__relatematch_8c_a0701752f4d644996e0713dd1873f9bf9.html) (but for more than one pattern parameter), but I have a problem during compilation (probably with linking).

This is my function written in C:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "funcapi.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"

// here I had to add path to headers because I got fatal error: lwgeom_geos.h: No such file or directory
#include "./postgis-3.0.0/liblwgeom/lwgeom_geos.h"
#include "./postgis-3.0.0/libpgcommon/lwgeom_pg.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* #define POSTGIS_DEBUG_LEVEL 4 */

/* My RelateMatchFunction */
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(myrelatematch);

Datum myrelatematch(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char *mat, *pat;
    text *mat_text, *pat_text;
    int result, arg;

    mat_text = (PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0));
    mat = text_to_cstring(mat_text);

    initGEOS(lwpgnotice, lwgeom_geos_error);

    for (arg=1; arg < PG_NARGS(); arg++)
    {
        if (!PG_ARGISNULL(arg))
        {
            pat_text = (PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(arg));
            pat = text_to_cstring(pat_text);

            result = GEOSRelatePatternMatch(mat, pat);
            if (result == 2)
            {
                lwfree(mat); lwfree(pat);
                lwpgerror("GEOSRelatePatternMatch: %s", lwgeom_geos_errmsg);
                PG_RETURN_NULL();
            } else if (result == 1)
            {
                lwfree(mat); lwfree(pat);
                PG_RETURN_BOOL(result);
            }
        }
    }
    PG_RETURN_BOOL(0);
}
```

Then I used `Makefile` from the tutorial:

```
MODULES = myrelatematch
EXTENSION = myrelatematch
DATA = myrelatematch--0.0.1.sql
PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

And this is my SQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
myrelatematch(text,variadic text[]) RETURNS int AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME','myrelatematch'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

Now if I run `make` on Ubuntu 18.04 there is no error. It creates shared object, if I run `sudo make install` there is no error but if I run `CREATE EXTENSION myrelatematch` in the database I got this error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/myrelatematch.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/myrelatematch.so: undefined symbol: lwgeom_geos_error
```

I am running **Ubuntu 18.04**, all libraries for Postgis are on the server (I am able to compile Postgis from source). **Postgresql version is 11.6**.

I am not experienced and I always find a problem with compilation some bigger part of software. I supposed there is a problem with linking the libraries but after all day of debugging I need a help.

**EDIT**

If I copy gcc command and add `-Wl,--no-undefined` I get the errors from linker:

```
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:26: undefined reference to `pg_detoast_datum'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:27: undefined reference to `text_to_cstring'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:29: undefined reference to `lwgeom_geos_error'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:29: undefined reference to `lwpgnotice'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:29: undefined reference to `initGEOS'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:35: undefined reference to `pg_detoast_datum'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:36: undefined reference to `text_to_cstring'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:38: undefined reference to `GEOSRelatePatternMatch'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:46: undefined reference to `lwfree'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:46: undefined reference to `lwfree'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:41: undefined reference to `lwfree'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:41: undefined reference to `lwfree'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:42: undefined reference to `lwgeom_geos_errmsg'
/home/username/myrelatematch/myrelatematch.c:42: undefined reference to `lwpgerror'
```

If I add `-L/home/username/myrelatematch/postgis-3.0.0/liblwgeom` there is no change and the error is the same.

Here is the complete gcc command:

```
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -L/usr/lib/llvm-6.0/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -Wl,--as-needed -L/home/username/myrelatematch/postgis-3.0.0/liblwgeom -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -o myrelatematch.so myrelatematch.o
```

Comment: Same issue, not resolved but:  1. add  "override CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -llwgeom" to Makefile, having lwgem libs should make you a little step forward. ... then I'm trying to modify the Makefile to point to compiled libs, sorry cannot do more, sharing my confs will just add confusion, I'll do with something more relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on these questions ([pgxs question - linking c-functions to external libraries](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/7632.1418418409%40sss.pgh.pa.us) and [PGXS ignores SHLIB_LINK when linking modules](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CABRT9RAnPw+O5RPUnT=fJs5yvMYN6w0XQNXsjDD=KNzfgL=jQg@mail.gmail.com)) I found solution.

[Here is the example of Makefile with third party libraries](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/uuid-ossp/Makefile)

And my Makefile for `GEOS`, `LIBLWGEOM` a `LIBPGCOMMON` libraries:

```
EXTENSION = vectgen        
DATA = vectgen--0.0.1.sql  
OBJS = vectgen.o
MODULE_big = vectgen

# postgres build stuff
SHLIB_LINK = -lgeos_c -llwgeom -lpgcommon
PG_LDFLAGS += -L /home/username/CLionProjects/test_geos/libpgcommon
PG_CPPFLAGS = -I /home/username/CLionProjects/test_geos/libpgcommon
PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

I have to changes `MODULES` for `MODULE_big`, then `SHLIB_LINK` is considered in compilation so `-l` flag works for libraries. After that I copy `libpgcommon` from PostGIS into my project and linked with `PG_LDFLAGS`.